# "When words aren't enough" or "that words aren't enough"?

Tags: grammar

I'm editing a video with some romantic songs, and I want to name it "For those moments when/that words aren't enough".

What are the merits of using [*when*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/when) (which indicates a time, AHDEL) vs. [*that*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/that) (used to refer to the event, action, or time just mentioned, AHDEL) in this sentence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Those moments" is an expression of time; "when" is a pronoun that refers to time. It's the appropriate choice.

You didn't ask, but similarly: "For those people that/who appreciate romance"--which pronoun should I use? Obviously, the pronoun that* refers to people: "For those people **who** appreciate romance."

(*See what I did there?)

Answer (score 0):

Use "when", without question. That is what I'd definitely use.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the others that **when** is the word to use.

That title will work because people will know what you mean, but you are talking about editing a video *for those moments when words won't be enough*.
Your product must be ready in advance for those moments when it will be needed.
That moment is not now or when someone gets your work, so a future suggestion of won't instead of a present suggestion of aren't, but people will know what you mean.